# Covariant return type is not recognized

Tags: c++

For some reason, up-to-date versions of both GCC and clang do not recognize return type covariance in this particular scenario. The error message is misleading:

```
error: return type of virtual function 'foo' is not covariant with the return
     type of the function it overrides ('derived *' is not derived from 'base *')
```

Here is the code:

```
class base
{
private:
  virtual base * foo() = 0;
};

template< class T >
class foo_default_impl : public virtual base
{
private:
  T * foo() override { return nullptr; }
};

class derived : public virtual base, private foo_default_impl< derived >
{
};

int main() {
  derived d{}; // error: return type of virtual function 'foo' is not covariant with the return type of the function it overrides ('derived *' is not derived from 'base *')
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `foo()` needs to return a `foo_default_impl *`, not a `T *`.

Comment: did previous versions compile your code? I wonder if this is because `derived` is not yet a complete type when it is passed to foo_default_impl : http://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#class.virtual-8

Comment: @KhouriGiordano : Why?  In the particular case we are considering, `T` will be `derived`, and `derived` is publicly derived from `base`.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano: I've just followed the link from marcinj, and see why you said that.

Comment: ..... but I am not sure if in this case derived is actually in-complete at that point

Comment: @marcinj : I think you should write that up as the answer.  The problem is `foo_default_impl::foo` is breaking the rules (return type is neither complete, nor `foo_default_impl`).  The error message could be better.

Comment: @marcin : It can't be complete.  One of the things about a complete type, is that you know it's size.  You can't know the size of a class until you know the size of its base classes.  We are currently trying to create one of those base classes!

Comment: @MartinBonner that makes sense :-)

Comment: Possibly you should apply the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern][https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern]

Comment: @KhouriGiordano : This *is* the CRTP!

Comment: I guess I meant apply it to `base`

Comment: There may be no benefit in returning a covariant type `T *` in my case, so I will be sticking to just returning `base *`. The point of the question was mostly not "how do I overcome the issue" but "what am I doing wrong".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's the thing. While to us it may appear that the compiler knows everything it needs to know about the types in question, the standard says otherwise.

[[temp.arg.type/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#arg.type-2)

> ... [ Note: **A template type argument may be an incomplete type**. — end note ]

[[basic.types/5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#5)

> **A class that has been declared but not defined**, an enumeration type in
>   certain contexts ([dcl.enum]), or an array of unknown bound or of
>   incomplete element type, **is an incompletely-defined object type**.46
>   **Incompletely-defined object types and cv void are incomplete types**
>   ([basic.fundamental]). Objects shall not be defined to have an
>   incomplete type.

[[class/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#2)

> A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared
>   immediately after the class-name is seen. The class-name is also
>   inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the
>   injected-class-name. For purposes of access checking, the
>   injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name. A
>   class-specifier is commonly referred to as a class definition. **A class
>   is considered defined after the closing brace of its class-specifier
>   has been seen** even though its member functions are in general not yet
>   defined. The optional attribute-specifier-seq appertains to the class;
>   the attributes in the attribute-specifier-seq are thereafter
>   considered attributes of the class whenever it is named.

The text in bold paints the simple picture that the compilers in question treat the type parameter T as an incomplete object type. It's as though you only forward declared it, like so:

```
class derived;
```

They cannot deduce that this forward declaration is a class derived from `base`. So they cannot accept it as a co-variant return type in the context of `foo_default_impl`. Like was pointed out by **@marcinj** [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548242/covariant-return-type-is-not-recognized#comment76088448_44548242):

[[class.virtual/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#class.virtual-8)

> If the class type in the covariant return type of D​::​f differs from
>   that of B​::​f, the class type in the return type of D​::​f shall be
>   complete at the point of declaration of D​::​f or shall be the class
>   type D.

Since `T` is neither complete, nor is it `foo_default_impl<T>` itself, it cannot be a co-variant return type.

Comment: I agree. Part of the error message _('derived *' is not derived from 'base *')_ made me think that compiler got confused with this code.

Comment: The point made in the comments above -- that `sizeof(complete_type)` must work -- also makes it clear why `derived` cannot be complete at that line.  We are defining a base of `derived`, how can we know how big `derived` is?