# C++ CRTP And Incomplete Class Definition

Tags: c++, crtp, incomplete-type

Is referring to derived class fields allowed in base definition when using CRTP?

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    constexpr int IntInDerived = T::SomeInt; // <--- Is This Valid
    using TypeInDerived = typename T::SomeType; // <--- Is This Valid
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    constexpr int SomeInt = 10;
    using SomeType = float;
};
```

I'm not sure because even though T::SomeInt and T::SomeType are dependent names, at moment Base is instantiated Derived is considered an incomplete type.

Comment: Relevant I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548242/covariant-return-type-is-not-recognized/44549084#44549084

Answer (score 0):

Apparently these are not valid when placed inside class definition block like in the question. However accessing T's members inside a method would be valid since methods are separately instantiated later.